# Failed to resolve - android maps utils

Tags: android, gradle, android-maps-utils

i'm creating module with GPS tracking. I've got there only track implementation.

What i need is PolyUtil so i set in gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
}
```

After gradle sync i've got error:

> Failed to resolve: com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4

**EDIT:**
This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the reason is that I am creating a library:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

After switch to application:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

**Error doesn't show anymore.**

This doesn't fix my problem but maybe it will solve someone's problem.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had to compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5' instead of 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5.+' that official docs suggest.